# SearchBar in Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I want to set the left margin of `searchBar` by right margin buttonbarleft and right margin of `searchBar` by leftbar buttonbarright

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add searchBar in the titleView and left & right button in the leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem respectively. It will produce a navigationBar as expected.

Comment: I also do the same. but the red color on the image is UISearchBar

Comment: @ThươngVănBùi I am not able to understand exact issue. Can you explain in more detail ? or you can share screenshot of what you have build till now and what is desired.

Comment: Currently UISearchBar is located on UINavigation. and two buttons on the UISearchBar, When clicked out, UISearchBar will execute the search event